# How to refer to a concrete class in TypeScript without repeating constructor parameters every time

Tags: typescript

This code works:

```
abstract class Foo {
    constructor(a: string, b: number) {
    }
}

class SpecificFoo extends Foo {}

function bar<F extends Foo>(klass: new (a: string, b: number) => F) {
    return new klass('hi', 1)
}

bar(SpecificFoo)
```

However, I have had to specify `(a: string, b: number)` both at the definition, and at the callsite, which is duplicative. With many functions that accept `F extends Foo`, and/or with long or complicated constructor parameters to `Foo`, this becomes problematic.

When I try `klass: new (...args: ConstructorParameters<F>) => F` instead, I get the following error:

> Type 'Foo' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): any'.(2344)

When I try `ConstructorParameters<typeof F>`, I get these errors:

> 'F' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693)
>
> Parameter 'args' of constructor signature from exported interface has or is using private name 'F'.(4065)

[TS Playground link for convenience](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYge2wg3gLABQCZS2AdpFAK7zZQAUwAXAjQJaUDmANAhDtKtALYgAplACUBEuQQBfEsuIkUaDAGUADhNicAZp1g48EgB4QJlACYYzBVSUO1K8TlUHAoAHkwIltZ2DrgAfEwA1qjowhIA7ggs7Fy8AkIIIuJSsgC8YViyRKTkUBIQtFCUmQkI0ZpMAOQAFpyNAgCM0iokJCA%20TLr6RiZm3WrEru4QntX9UABM-oFWNvZY4VExYHGJTAB0hz48OwgAwlQ09BCMAAo%20wKLlUmD%20YXkFmEXypeWV1ZRavV0E1Wu0EF0ehMph4vPMAMzLIJrULYCLA06AvaHfbHU4XajQa53B5PaxQV4QACeemwhiw7wQ%20UKchKZDKFSqNUSGNBbU640UQA).

Is there a nicer way to type this?

Comment: what about this: `ConstructorParameters<typeof Foo>`? Would this work for you?

Comment: Ah, yes, that does seem to work! It's unfortunate because it can't really be abstracted into a cleaner utility type, but it's better than what I have now – thank you!